# Help with Atomic Blender addon

Tags: add-on, import

When loading PDB files into blender with the [Atomic Blender addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/PDB), only the atoms are present but no bonds, despite selecting sticks/bonds and varying a number of other settings.

[image]

Comment: Is this have to do with [bioBlender](http://www.bioblender.eu/)? You may find help here...

Comment: Unfortunately not. Its the Atomic blender plugin for blender

Comment: @Polosson I think the question is asking about [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?235003-Atomic-Blender-for-loading-PDB-files-into-Blender-2-5)

Comment: Have you tried this with the examaple files provided here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/PDB ? I don't know the file format is it possible that the file you're loading has no data for bonds?